# Visual C++ linker, where does ws2_32.lib got drawn in?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I'm very curious about this question I encounter.

First, I have a tiny tsocket.cpp

```
#include <Winsock2.h>

int main()
{
     SOCKET s = 0;
     closesocket(s);
     return 0;
}
```

When compiling it using Visual Studio 2013,

```
cl /DUNICODE /DWINVER=0x501 tsocket.cpp
```

Linking fails:

```
tsocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__closesocket@4 referenced in function _main
tsocket.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

but when I add at first line

```
#include <afx.h>
```

Linking succeeds.

I preprocess tsocket.h (`cl /P`) and examine `tsocket.i` , I find no linker hint like

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

Then, I hope to know who tells link.exe to link in ws2_32.lib ?

Comment: The /defaultlib directive can also come from libraries.  It is mfcs120u.lib that pulls it in.  Which you got pulled in by including afx.h

Comment: The .i file should hold the source for the '#pragma comment' line.  If you scroll a bit up from the line itself you should be able to see it.

Comment: No, Ofek. That's not the case. You did not try it. MFC's own source code sees ``#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`` from some of its headers, but user's code does not. For example, lib /extract mfcs90.lib, and check into dllmodulx.obj, you can see ``/DEFAULTLIB:"ws2_32.lib"``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippets are taken from VS2015 outputs. First, set the linker to /VERBOSE, to get -

```
...
          Loaded mfcs140ud.lib(nolib.obj)
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:atls.lib
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:ole32.lib
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:oleaut32.lib
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:wininet.lib
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:ws2_32.lib     <---- !
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:mswsock.lib
1>   Processed /DISALLOWLIB:nafxcwd.lib 
...
```

which hints to look into mfcs140ud.lib.  Next open a VS command prompt, cd to %VSDIR%\vc\atlmfc\lib and type

```
dumpbin /directives mfcs140ud.lib > c:\temp.txt
```

To get (in temp.txt) :

```
Dump of file mfcs140ud.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib

   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /include:??3@YAXPAX@Z
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:atls.lib
   /merge:ATL=.rdata
   /DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:ole32.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:shell32.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:oleaut32.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:shlwapi.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:wininet.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:ws2_32.lib    <---------!
```

It could have been nice if the shipped mfc sources were complete enough to pinpoint the exact source that does the #pragma comment(ws2_32), but it seems it isn't.  The closest I can see is

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")
```

in sockcore.cpp.

---

Edit:  The exact source is in %VSDIR%\vc\atlmfc\include\atlsocket.h.  You can find the line

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

there - and it is indirectly included in mfc's precompiled header, via  %VSDIR%\vc\atlmfc\include\stdafx.h.

Comment: Great. I verified that the link.exe ``/VERBOSE`` switch works the same way since Visual C++ 2005.